# Weird `(point-max)` in testing function in `magic-mode-alist`

Tags: find-file, narrowing

Why does the below function always print `4001` when opening a large file?

```
(require 'cl-lib)

(defun custom-test-p ()
  (with-current-buffer (current-buffer)
    (print (point-max))) ; 4001
  nil)

(cl-pushnew (cons #'custom-test-p #'fundamental-mode) magic-mode-alist :test #'equal)
```

For file which `(point-max)` < 4001, the output seems correct. But for relative 'large' file, the output is always 4001.

Tested in `emacs -q`. Emacs version: `GNU Emacs 29.1 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin22.6.0, Carbon Version 169 AppKit 2299.7) of 2023-09-02`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
magic-mode-regexp-match-limit is a variable defined in ‘files.el’.

Its value is 4000

Upper limit on ‘magic-mode-alist’ regexp matches.
Also applies to ‘magic-fallback-mode-alist’.
```

The buffer will be narrowed, in which case `(point-max)` will reflect the narrowed limit.

Comment: Thanks for the information that variable. The document says `Each element looks like (REGEXP . FUNCTION) or (MATCH-FUNCTION . FUNCTION).` So I've thought that variable will only be applied to the former (regexp) case.

Comment: `M-x report-emacs-bug` to improve the documentation.